# Amazon Product Search - What is the service URI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cocoa

I am using the Amazon Product Search WSDL in an objective-c project. Since Objective-c does not have any direct support for SOAP, I cannot just use the wsdl and leave all the other processing for my app.

I want to know what the service uri for the amazon product search is. This is the WSDL I am using

```
http://soap.amazon.com/schemas2/AmazonWebServices.wsdl
```

Comment: You're asking us to grovel through the XML for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word 'service' is only in the xml 3 times, so I'm assuming that what you're looking for is:

```
<service name="AmazonSearchService"> 
    <!-- Endpoint for Amazon Web APIs --> 
    <port name="AmazonSearchPort" binding="typens:AmazonSearchBinding"> 
        <soap:address location="http://soap.amazon.com/onca/soap2"/> 
    </port> 
</service>
```

Edit: Visiting [that url](http://soap.amazon.com/onca/soap2) in a browser shows a page with this message:

> Amazon Ecommerce Web Service 3.0 has
>   been deprecated after many years of
>   useful service on March 31st 2008.
>   Please upgrade to the Amazon
>   Associates Web Service 4.0 as detailed
>   in the [migration guide](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?categoryID=12&externalID=627). Please visit
>   [Amazon Associates Web Service
>   Developer Forum](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/forum.jspa?forumID=9&start=0) for more information.
>   If you came to this page from an RSS
>   feed, visit [Amazon's Product RSS Feeds](http://www.amazon.com/b/?ie=UTF8&node=390052011)
>   page for an upgrade.

The migration guide has many WSDL locations, depending on which national site you want; the US site's wsdl is at http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl and the schema is at http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.xsd

Comment: That is what I assumed. But when I use this service url - http://soap.amazon.com/onca/soap2?Service=AWSECommerceService, I get an error that the host name could not be found, which is why the question here.

Comment: Works for me: “soap.amazon.com is an alias for webservices.amazon.com.
webservices.amazon.com has address 72.21.211.36” —host(1)

Comment: @lostInTransit: clicking on your link gives me a page that says that the "Amazon Ecommerce Web Service 3.0" was deprecated in March 2008, and that you should read the Migration Guide for information on how to switch to version 4.0 - I've updated my answer with this text, and links.

Answer (score 0):

Head out to 
https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html and you will be able to access the full documentation. The SOAP endpoints are listed here:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01/DG/index.html?SOAPEndpoints.html